# Templates non-type parameters to a static member function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a template that takes a template to a non-type parameter to a static member function:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class C {
public:
    static void method()
    {
        cout << "C::method" << endl;
    }
};

typedef void (C::*pMethod)();
template<typename T, pMethod>
void callingFunction()

{
    T c;
    pMethod aPointerToMember = &T::method;
    (c.*aPointerToMember)();
}


int main()
{
    callingFunction<C, &C::method>();

    return 0;
}
```

But I always get error when calling the function in main:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'callingFunction()' // mingw
```

If The member function is not static it works, how can I make it work with static function ?

Thanks.

Thank you

Comment: Static methods are just syntactic sugar for free standing functions... (well, not exactly, but almost)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a static member function, change your typedef to `typedef void (*pMethod)();` - as if it was a free function.

Comment: then I get this:  error: 'aPointerToMember' cannot be used as a member pointer, since it is of type 'void (*)()'

Comment: you have to change (c.*aPointerToMember)(); to (aPointerToMember)();

Comment: @vBx: You'll need to call it as if it was a free function as well - remove the `c.*`. A static function isn't associated with any class instance.